# AdMob: filter ads for kids

Tags: android, ios, admob, ads

I managed to run AdMob sdk on my Android & iOS application and it's displaying ads perfectly.

I am trying to filter the ads to only include ads that a child would click.

In AdMob you will have a list of ads categories allowed by default and you only can ban fifty of them. I don't think that this is the approach anyway.

Anyone had this experience before? Do you suggest to change ads provider anything else than AdMob? Please, consider mentioning clear and valuable explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admob do not provide such an approach.

Admob only allow blocking a limited number of categories and subcategories. and leaves the others active. (This is kind of their strategy for advertising).

Nevertheless, you can add other ads networks to your AdMob as mediation networks. (admob will also provide you with ads from these networks).

**[List of popular ads networks](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/mobile-app-monetizing-networks/)**

**List of Ads networks that provide some kind of filters:**

1. Adfonic: a middle east advertising network. allows inserting keywords for your app as categories and they will try to provide you with ads in the same category. They are still beginners. maybe they are good for the middle east, not more.
2. Chartboost: if you have a game app. yeehaa, you are saved. Chartboost provide game ads only for game apps. but, unfortunately you can't integrate chartboost with admob. it works alone.

> **3. MobFox: allow category blocks as much as you want. Ex. you can keep games and educational ads. Also, it could be integrated with AdMob.**

[Admob Mediation Networks Integration](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation-networks)

Comment: I have integrated MobFox publisher ID to my AdMob account. However, AdMob Network is still in the list and my game presents the absurd ads from AdMob Network. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you develop apps specifically for children, I would suggest using COPPA Compliant SDK, such as KIDOZ - http://kidoz.net. They have all kinds of solutions for developers in the kids' segment.

Comment: Hi Tom, I m also trying to use Kidoz for my iOS Swift Native iOS app. I have integrated Kidoz SDK in my app successfully but every time I m getting error 'Interstitialload falied'.Unable to load 'Interstitial' Ads. Could you please share your source code related to Kidoz integration ?